# I'm trying to install openjdk11 in win 11

Tags: java, chocolatey

I've tried running this command in PowerShell as an admin:

```
choco install -y  openjdk11
```

and it returns this error:  [image: Image of error]

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the --ignore-checksum option?  That shouldn't be necessary, and it not recommended.  Have you reached out to the original package maintainer? You can do this via their GitHub Repository here: https://github.com/johanjanssen/ChocolateyPackages/issues

Answer (score 1):

I use "winget" to download packages from Powershell. Firstly, you have to search for the package, which would look like this:

> winget search openjdk

This will provide many options along with the ID which you will need to install the program.

To install, use

> winget install {Program ID}